# How to pass VAST ad response to ImaAdsLoader in androidx.media3 exo player

Tags: android, androidx, exoplayer, exoplayer-media-item

Is there any way to directly pass vast ad response to androidx media3 exo player instead of passing adTag url

Below is example of passing adTag url

```
 private AdsLoader getClientSideAdsLoader(MediaItem.AdsConfiguration adsConfiguration) {
        // The ads loader is reused for multiple playbacks, so that ad playback can resume.
        if (clientSideAdsLoader == null) {
            clientSideAdsLoader = new ImaAdsLoader.Builder(/* context= */ this)

                    .build();
        }
        clientSideAdsLoader.setPlayer(player);
        return clientSideAdsLoader;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 MediaSource.Factory mediaSourceFactory =
                new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(this)
                        .setLocalAdInsertionComponents(this::getClientSideAdsLoader, /* adViewProvider= */ playerView);

        player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
                .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
                .build();

        playerView.setPlayer(player);


        MediaItem mediaItem =
                new MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setUri("<DASH URI>")
                        .setAdsConfiguration(
                new MediaItem.AdsConfiguration.Builder(Uri.parse("vast ad url")).build())
                        .build();


        // Set the media item to be played.
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        // Prepare the player.
        player.prepare();
        // Start the playback.
        player.play();

}
```

I went through the documentation of androidx.media3 exo player but couldn't find any way. For exo player 2.11,  we can pass as below

```
ImaAdsLoader.Builder builder = new ImaAdsLoader.Builder(mContext);
ImaSdkSettings imaSdkSettings = ImaSdkFactory.getInstance().createImaSdkSettings();
builder = builder.setImaSdkSettings(imaSdkSettings);
ImaAdsLoader imaAdsLoader = builder.buildForAdsResponse(adResource);
```

is it possible to pass similary for androidx media3 exo player

Comment: did you find any solution? have same case after migration on media3

Answer (score 0):

```
String vmapXMLString = "<vmap:VMAP ........";


MediaItem mediaItem =
                new MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setUri(<mpd_url>)
                        .setAdsConfiguration(
                                new MediaItem.AdsConfiguration.Builder(Util.getDataUriForString("text/xml",vmapXMLString)).build())
                        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**